# Angular.module is not working

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs and currently practising it .I have a simple example like this .

My View Index.cshtml

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">    
<div class="show-scope-demo">
        <div ng-controller="MainController">
            <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>
            <div ng-controller="subController1">
                <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>
                <div ng-controller="subController2">
                    <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my controller is MyJsScript.js

```
(function (angular) {

angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.timeOfDay = 'morning';
    $scope.name = 'sapan';
}]);
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('subController1', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'sapan';
}]);
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('subController2', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.timeOfDay = 'Evening';
    $scope.name = 'Tapan';
}]);
})(window.angular);
```

in this case I am getting error

> "[ng:areq] Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined"

But if I am changing my controller like this

```
(function (angular) {
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.timeOfDay = 'morning';
    $scope.name = 'sapan';
}]);
myApp.controller('subController1', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'sapan';
}]);
myApp.controller('subController2', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.timeOfDay = 'Evening';
    $scope.name = 'Tapan';
}]);
})(window.angular);
```

It is working perfectly without any error .

Can anyone please tell me what is the exact difference between these two  syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS defining angular.module() multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371410/angularjs-defining-angular-module-multiple-times)

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
```

you're **defining** a **new** module named "MyApp" (and thus effectively overwrite the module that was previously defined with the same name).

To get a reference to a previously defined module named "MyApp", the correct syntax is

```
angular.module('MyApp')
```

without the array of dependencies.