# $ionicPlatform.ready not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Im having a problem, the code inside $ionicPlatform.ready is not firing if I add my router file and the controller file but I can not find the problem.

Template and controller is working fine.

index.html

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/core/router/app.router.js"></script>
<script src="js/feature/notification/notification.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

app.js

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ionic'])
    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
            }

            if (window.StatusBar) {
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
            console.log('##################');
        });
    });
```

app.router.js

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ionic', 'ui.router'])
    .config(Router);

Router.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function Router($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('notifications', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'js/feature/notification/notification.html',
            controller: 'NotificationCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'model'
        });
}
```

notifications.js

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('NotificationCtrl', NotificationCtrl);

function NotificationCtrl() {
    var model = this;
    console.log('Test');
}
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code wrapped in `$ionicPlatform.ready` does not run because you are defining your app module more than once when it should only be defined in your `app.js`.  Subsequent calls to the module should leave off the dependency annotations.  In this case, you can change the line in `app.router.js` from `.module('app', ['ionic', 'ui.router'])` to `.module('app')`.

Another thing to note is that with Ionic, you don't need to inject `ui-router` yourself as it is included in the Ionic bundle.

You should not, however, remove `Router.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];` unless you are using an automated annotation tool such as `ng-annotate` due to potential issues when minifying your code (thanks, @AdityaSingh).

(Edited for clarity and accuracy.)

Comment: Okay, so If I understand rigth Im overwritting the module ? It's working fine with your solution

Comment: Your module definition should only occur once (in your app.js file), then you call your module in subsequent files without the dependency annotations. I was digging a bit more to find exactly how the code is interpreting this and why it breaks in order to answer your question precisely and came across this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371410/angularjs-defining-angular-module-multiple-times).  The comments on the accepted answer seem to summarize it well.  To paraphrase: the initial module definition can be seen as a setter, and subsequent module calls can be seen as getters.

Comment: Just to add that the explicit annotation `Router.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];` should not be removed unless you are using an automated tool like `ng-annotate`. Annotations help avoiding errors in production minified build. Check `ng-strict-di` for further use case

Comment: @aditya doesn't ionic take care of that for the router? I know it's important for all other dependencies, but I would like to know if I was mistaken regarding the router.

Comment: No. Ionic doesn't deals with explicit routing. If you remove the lone above and minify, chances are your code might not work. Use a build tool like `gulp`  and `ng-annotate` to add explicit annotations.

Comment: @AdityaSingh I stand corrected.  I could have sworn that I saw an explicit annotation for `$stateProvider` & `$urlRouterProvider` in `ionic.bundle.js`, but after looking into it again, I guess I was wrong.  I am updating my answer to reflect this.  Thanks!